# Spring Web - 405 method not allowed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc, backend

I recently tried to program a simple api in spring.
When I try it with postman, the only two working endpoints are the `fetchAllMovie` and the `createMovie`. The others (with request parameter) give a response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-11-30T14:38:34.396+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "path": "/api/movies"
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/movies")
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MovieMapper movieMapper;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Movie> fetchAllMovie() {
        return movieService.getAllMovie();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public MovieDto createMovie(@RequestBody MovieCreationDto movieCreationDto) {
        Movie movie = movieMapper.creationDtoToModel(movieCreationDto);
        return movieMapper.modelToDto(movieRepository.save(movie));
    }

    @GetMapping("/{movieId}")
    public MovieDto fetchMovieById(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) throws MovieNotFoundException {
        Movie movie = movieRepository.findById(movieId).orElseThrow(MovieNotFoundException::new);
        return movieMapper.modelToDto(movie);
    }
}
```

So if I send a **GET** request like `http://localhost:8080/api/movies?movieId=619fa9d9b0c30252474b9a01` I get the error, but if I send a **GET** or **POST** request like `http://localhost:8080/api/movies` i can get all of the data from the data base or I can **POST** in it. (Of course with the proper request body)

> Note it: Not only the **GET** req not working. Anything with request parameter gives me this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @PathVariable is used to send parameter in path, like this: http://localhost:8080/api/movies/619fa9d9b0c30252474b9a01

If you want to send it using URL you specified, you need to use annotation @RequestParam

Comment: I understood the problem, but i have no luck. Chenged every `@PathVariable` to `@RequestParam`, but the bug is still present.

Comment: If you changed to request param, you should also change @GetMapping("/{movieId}") to @GetMapping("something") and then use http://localhost:8080/api/movies/something?movieId=619fa9d9b0c30252474b9a01, you already have empty @GetMapping to fetch all movies

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **@PathVariable** as the input parameter, then you should call the endpoint in the following way:

http://localhost:8080/api/movies/619fa9d9b0c30252474b9a01

If you would like to use the **@RequestParameter** then call the api like this:

http://localhost:8080/api/movies?movieId=619fa9d9b0c30252474b9a01

Quick summary:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestparam-vs-pathvariable